# How do I hide a URL in a prompt when I'm using a masked URL forwarding?

Tags: javascript

I have a URL [themaraudersmap.xyz](http://themaraudersmap.xyz) that I've set up to URL forward to another site where I have a map, but before they can see the map I have a prompt for a password. The prompt comes up and it has the other sites URL in the title of it, I would like to hide that if I can.

Comment: Only input fields of type password, otherwise you need some dynamic magic, probably best to avoid a prompt

Comment: is this a basic authentication prompt? if so, you can't change the title. if it's a regular prompt(), you can launch it from the other site, and postMessage the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.
You can try to use some external jQuery library, like $.dialog.